2-category structure on Mod(R)
Apologies for the basic question but I'm curious to know if there is an ``interesting" $2$-category structure on the category of modules over a ring $R$.
Essentially what is not clear to me if $M,N$ are two $R$-modules, what should be a $2$-morphism, that is if $f,g:M\to N$ are two $R$-module morphisms, what should be a morphism
$H:f\to g$?
I suppose I could just take the "trival" category, i.e. that there is no non-trivial morphisms, but I'm curious if there is an ``interesting/non-trivial" one.

Not an answer to your question, but something related you may or may not already be familiar with -- the category of $R$-algebras has an interesting 2-categorical structure where 1-morphisms are bimodules and 2-morphisms are the obvious notion of bimodule homomorphisms.

In 1958 Peter Hilton introduced the "homotopy theory of modules," in which a homotopy between $R$-module homomorphisms $f,g: M \rightarrow N$ is a factorization of $f-g$ through a projective $R$-module. In the resulting htpy. theory of modules, homotopy-equivalent modules have the same higher $Ext$-groups (here you must think of $Ext$ as a functor in the first variable). This was used to great effect in stable htpy theory by Adams, Priddy, and Margolis, and in representation theory by Auslander. I don't know if Hilton's homotopies are 2-morphisms in a 2-category, but probably somebody knows.

P.S. My last comment undersold the long history of applications of Hilton's homotopy theory of modules: it's not just the four people I mentioned. Since Hilton's introduction of the idea, many people in many areas of math have used this kind of "stable module theory" or "homotopy theory of modules," too many for me to try to outline the history--better to do a web search if you want to read more.

Interesting question. Given that the homotopy relation is symmetric, I would expect each hom-category to be a groupoid... but at the same time, while I can see natural ways to define composition and an identity 2-cell ($f-f=0$ factors through... zero?), I don't see why the inverse of a homotopy $(P,u,v):f\to g$ ($P$ the projective module, $f-g=vu$) should give the identity. But I'm not trying very hard, just thinking out loud!
